# how to get the first item in nested, filtered array in javascirpt

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I've got an array:

```
const aContracts = [[ '0x8ae127d224094cb1b27e1b28a472e588cbcc7620', 0 ],
  [ '0xcbf4ab00b6aa19b4d5d29c7c3508b393a1c01fe3', 0 ],
  [ '0x03cd191f589d12b0582a99808cf19851e468e6b5', 0 ],
  [ '0x0b3f868e0be5597d5db7feb59e1cadbb0fdda50a', 1 ]]
```

And I'm trying to filter using the second item in each sub-array.  So I used:

`const aGoodContracts = aContracts.filter(contracts => contracts[1]===1);`

And I get:

`[["0x0b3f868e0be5597d5db7feb59e1cadbb0fdda50a", 1]]`

However, I want [EDIT I want an array of all the "good" contracts]:

`"0x0b3f868e0be5597d5db7feb59e1cadbb0fdda50a"`

So I tried a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689520/how-to-filter-array-of-arrays):
`const aGoodContracts = aContracts.map(k => k.filter(contracts => contracts[1]===1));`

But I get:

`[[], [], [], []]`

What am I missing?

Comment: As it is, aGoodContracts[0][0] will give you your string.  But what would you want if more than one contract had 1 as the second element?

Comment: an array of all those contracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `map()` your result to pick out the first element in the array. This will leave you with an array, and if you just want the first value (like your expected output) grab the zero index element.

```js
const aContracts = [[ '0x8ae127d224094cb1b27e1b28a472e588cbcc7620', 0 ],
  [ '0xcbf4ab00b6aa19b4d5d29c7c3508b393a1c01fe3', 0 ],
  [ '0x03cd191f589d12b0582a99808cf19851e468e6b5', 0 ],
  [ '0x0b3f868e0be5597d5db7feb59e1cadbb0fdda50a', 1 ]]

const aGoodContracts = aContracts.filter(contracts => contracts[1]===1).map(c => c[0]);
console.log(aGoodContracts);
console.log(aGoodContracts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const aContracts = [[ '0x8ae127d224094cb1b27e1b28a472e588cbcc7620', 0 ],
  [ '0xcbf4ab00b6aa19b4d5d29c7c3508b393a1c01fe3', 0 ],
  [ '0x03cd191f589d12b0582a99808cf19851e468e6b5', 0 ],
  [ '0x0b3f868e0be5597d5db7feb59e1cadbb0fdda50a', 1 ]]
const aGoodContracts = aContracts.filter(contracts => contracts[1]===1)[0]
console.log(aGoodContracts[0])
```